# How to solve StopIteration error in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements, generator, break

I have just read a bunch of posts on how to handle the StopIteration error in Python, I had trouble solving my particular example.I just want to print out from 1 to 20 with my code but it prints out error StopIteration. My code is:(I am a completely newbie here so please don't block me.)

```
def simpleGeneratorFun(n):

    while n<20:
        yield (n)
        n=n+1
    # return [1,2,3]

x = simpleGeneratorFun(1)
while x.__next__() <20:
    print(x.__next__())
    if x.__next__()==10:
        break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you use `x.__next__()` it gets the next yielded number - you do not check every one yielded and 10 is skipped - so it continues to run after 20 and breaks.

Fix:

```
def simpleGeneratorFun(n):

    while n<20:
        yield (n)
        n=n+1
    # return [1,2,3]

x = simpleGeneratorFun(1)
while True:
    try:
        val = next(x) # x.__next__() is "private", see @Aran-Frey comment 
        print(val)
        if val == 10:  
            break
    except StopIteration as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Comment: Please use the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function instead of `__next__`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the lesson. I try my best to learn.

Comment: I tried next but it says: "AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'"

Comment: @BarishAhsen Copy the code _exactly_ into http://pyfiddle.io - choose 2.7 or 3.x - it works for both. If it does not work for you, elaborate. You probably mis-copied something.

Answer (score 4):

First, in each loop iteration, you're advancing the iterator 3 times by making 3 separate calls to `__next__()`, so the `if x.__next__()==10` might never be hit since the 10th element might have been consumed earlier. Same with missing your while condition.

Second, there are usually better patterns in python where you don't need to make calls to `next` directly. For example, if you have finite iterator, use a for loop to automatically break on StopIteration:

```
x = simpleGeneratorFun(1)
for i in x:
    print i
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the lesson. I take note from your tutorial.